# how to use a function in from clause and passing conlum is a parameter in sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
CREATE FUNCTION EXPLAIN_GET_MSGS
    (@EXPLAIN_REQUESTER VARCHAR(128),
     @INLOCALE VARCHAR(33))
RETURNS @mytable TABLE (EXPLAIN_REQUESTER VARCHAR(128),
                        MSG VARCHAR(4096))
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @mytable 
       SELECT 
           A.A_EXPLAIN_REQUESTER, F.LOCALE, F.MSG
       FROM 
           EXPLAIN_DIAGNOSTIC AS A,
           EXPLAIN_GET_MSG2 (@INLOCALE, A.A_CODE,
                             (SELECT TOKEN 
                              FROM EXPLAIN_DIAGNOSTIC_DATA B
                              WHERE A.A_EXPLAIN_REQUESTER = B.EXPLAIN_REQUESTER
                                AND B.ORDINAL = 1),
                             (SELECT TOKEN 
                              FROM EXPLAIN_DIAGNOSTIC_DATA B
                              WHERE A.A_EXPLAIN_REQUESTER = B.EXPLAIN_REQUESTER
                                AND B.ORDINAL = 2),
                             (SELECT TOKEN 
                              FROM EXPLAIN_DIAGNOSTIC_DATA B
                              WHERE A.A_EXPLAIN_REQUESTER = B.EXPLAIN_REQUESTER
                                AND B.ORDINAL = 3)) as F
       WHERE
          (EXPLAIN_REQUESTER IS NULL OR
           EXPLAIN_REQUESTER = A.A_EXPLAIN_REQUESTER)

    RETURN 
END
```

How can I pass `A.A_CODE` into function `EXPLAIN_GET_MSG2`? Please heplp me

Comment: You should use `cross apply` to 'join' a function

Comment: thank you so much HoneyBadger, it's work with me